# Unwind segue causing fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error, ibaction, unwind-segue

I keep getting fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I know the general sense of the error, however I don't know what I'm doing wrong to cause it.

I've narrowed the issue down to an unwind segue of mind:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData
import Alamofire
import FastImageCache
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewControllerTabBar: UITabBarController {

var shouldLogin = false
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        if user != nil {
        } else {
            shouldLogin = true
        }
    }
}

var nextURLRequest: NSURLRequest?
var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 99/255, green: 222/255, blue: 154/255, alpha: 1)

    if let fetchRequest = coreDataStack.model.fetchRequestTemplateForName("UserFetchRequest") {

        let results = try! coreDataStack.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [User]

        user = results.first
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if shouldLogin {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
        shouldLogin = false
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func unwindToPhotoBrowser (segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "login" && segue.destinationViewController.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController.classForCoder()) {
        let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        if let oauthLoginViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? OauthLoginViewController {
            oauthLoginViewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
        }

        if self.user != nil {
            coreDataStack.context.deleteObject(user!)
            coreDataStack.saveContext()

        }
    }
}
}
```

The issue seems to be with

```
@IBAction func unwindToPhotoBrowser (segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

I've double checked my identifier and the connection in the story board. I have a similar project that uses a similar set up for login and that project seems to get the same error when this IBAction is removed so that's why I think it might be the issue. When I search for the action in the Find Navigator it doesn't show up with the "M" icon beside it whereas with my other project is does.

Comment: NBD, but it's better to use if let for "if self.user != nil". Then you don't have to force unwrap user.

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint to see which line is causing the problem?

Comment: @Paulw11 yup. It seems to be in issue with that @ IBAction for the unwind segue but I can't figure out what the issue is with it

Comment: Why do you have an unwind segue in a tab bar controller?  Is this controller also in a navigation controller or are you presenting another VC modally on top ?

Comment: @Paulw11 it's more of a navigation controller